# FLUIDTEMPLATE Section ... does not exist

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

I am using TYPO3 9.5.20
I try to test a FLUIDTEMPLATE implementation and I get an `Oops, ...` with `Section "PageHeader" does not exist`.

Here my template file:

```xml
    <f:layout name="Layout1ColumnPage" />
    
    <f:section name="WholeContent">
       <div id="whole-content">

          <f:format.raw>{contentNormal}</f:format.raw>
           <f:format.raw>{contentLeft}</f:format.raw>
          <f:format.raw>{contentRight}</f:format.raw>
      </div>
    </f:section>
    
    <f:section name="MainContent">
       <div id="main-content">
          <f:format.raw>{contentLeft}</f:format.raw>
       </div>
    </f:section>
    
    <f:section name="SideContent">
       <div id="side-content">
          <f:format.raw>{contentRight}</f:format.raw>
       </div>
    </f:section>
    
    <f:section name="PageHeader">
        <div id="page-header">
            <div class = "body" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <div class = "header w200">
                    <div class = "headTD">
                        <f:image src = "fileadmin/Page/Resources/Public/Images/Country-Radio-2020.jpg"  alt="HeaderImage" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                --- Ende Image ---
            </div>   
        </div>
    </f:section>
    
    <f:section name="PageFooter">
       <div id="page-footer">
          <div id="footer-notice"> <p>This is the page footer area.</p> </div>
       </div>
    </f:section>
```

Here my layout file

```xml
    <div id="page">
       <f:render section="PageHeader" />
       <div id="page-body">
          <div id="page-title">{data.title}</div>
          <f:render section="WholeContent" />
          <div id="page-body-end">&nbsp;</div>
       </div>
       <f:render section="PageFooter" />
    </div>
```

Here my setup file:

```
page = PAGE 
page.typeNum = 0
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE 
page.10 {
    format = html
    # Pfad zu der HTML Vorlage der Webseite 
    // file = fileadmin/Page/Resources/Private/Templates/CRtemplate.html
    templateName = CRtemplate
    # Pfad zu eingebundenen Partials 
    partialRootPaths.1 = fileadmin/Page/Resources/Private/Partials/
    # Pfad zur Layout Datei 
    layoutRootPaths.1 = fileadmin/Page/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    # Pfad zur Layout Datei 
    templateRootPaths.1 = fileadmin/Page/Resources/Private/Templates/    
    file.cObject = CASE
    file.cObject {
        key {
            data = levelfield: -1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
            override.field = TSFE:page|backend_layout
        }
        # Einbindung des ersten HTML Templates 
        1 = TEXT
        1.value = fileadmin/Page/Resources/Private/Layouts/Layout1ColumnPage.html
          
        # Einbindung des zweiten HTML Templates 
        2 = TEXT
        2.value = fileadmin/Page/Resources/Private/Layouts/Layout2ColumnPage.html
    }
    variables {
        # Verknüpfung der Inhalte mit dem Backend Layout 
        contentNormal < styles.content.get
        contentNormal.select.where = colPos = 10
        contentLeft < styles.content.get
        contentLeft.select.where = colPos = 11
        contentRight < styles.content.get
        contentRight.select.where = colPos = 12     
    }
}
```

In my opinion sections are defined in the right way. If I delete in the layout file render of `PageHeader` then I got the message that he cannot find section `WholeContent`. So it seems to be a general problem.

**EDIT**

As Bernd mentioned below, in Typo3 9.5.20 the setting of the rootPath is only possible as an area. example

```
templateRootPaths.1 = fileadmin/Page/Resources/Private/Templates/
```

But the 9.5 documentation still says, that both is possible!

Have also edited the above code!

Comment: please edit your question and add the filenames (including pathes from web root)

Answer (score 1):

I can't make out an error for sure, but there are some aspects you might consider for your templating:

- Your templates miss an header with namespace declartions like

```xml
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
      xmlns:n="http://typo3.org/ns/GeorgRinger/News/ViewHelpers"
      data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
:
</html>
```

- You only define one path. That was usual in the beginning of fluid and replaced with paths arrays. (I don't know whether this still works with single path declarations)

```
         # Pfad zur Layout Datei 
         templateRootPaths.1 = fileadmin/Page/Resources/Private/Templates/   
         # Pfad zu eingebundenen Partials 
         partialRootPaths.1 = fileadmin/Page/Resources/Private/Partials/
         # Pfad zur Layout Datei 
         layoutRootPaths.1 = fileadmin/Page/Resources/Private/Layouts/
```

- your template declaration is weird:

  - first you avoid a declaration of `file` by commenting
  - then you define a template by `templateName`
  - which is asided with a `file.cObject` where you miss that backend layouts might be declared in pageTS and are no longer just numbers (no default value in `case`)

Meanwhile you can get the evaluation of `backend_layout` and `backend_layout_next_level` with the core defined typoscript data `pagelayout` which results in the simple declaration:

```
page.10 {
    templateName {
        data = pagelayout
        ifEmpty = default
    }
}
```

You might add a special fluid variable to debug the values in the `backend_layout` fields:

```
page.10 {
    variables {
        pagelayout = TEXT
        pagelayout.data = pagelayout
    }
}
```

minor topics:

- Don't store your templates in `fileadmin/`. Use a site extension.
- `{variable->f:format.raw()}` is shorter and most times more readable than  `<f:format.raw>{variable}</f:format.raw>`

Comment: thanks a lot. It is always a problem with Typo3 examples. It is changing a lot and sometimes you get lost, wich is still valid and which not.

Comment: My understanding was, that in templates should be only includes code between body. I But I tried the html code, but it doesn't helped.

Comment: In the 9.5 documentation layoutRootPath and layoutRootPaths are both still valid.

Comment: And so there also ìs `partialRootpath` and `partialRootPaths` there is no `templateRootPath`, only `templateRootPaths`.

Comment: unbelievable, the Typo3 9.5 documentation has an error, rootPath only working as an area! Thans very much! That took me some days to get it working.

Comment: the documentation also is open source as TYPO3 itself. If you detect an error, or you think something needs more explanation, use the button `Edit on github` on top of the page and create a pull request.